# Reverse (or repopulate) a Google Docs Form

Tags: google-sheets

I created a  Google Docs [form](http://www.google.com/forms/about/) that collects (mostly) biographical and contact data from users. Now I would like to reverse the process and repopulate the form with each user's input, one page per user. I guess this is like Word's mail merge.

I see that Google Docs has a [scripting language](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en), but is there a simpler way to re-generate these form submissions without learning another scripting language? Cosmetics aren't at all important in this use case, I would just like to provide the user data to another audience without asking them to navigate a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

With some more searching I found that someone wrote Google Sheets add-on that does just this. The add-on is [Save as Doc](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-as-doc/iekpcmcpnbgoldpmhfbioecljjjjnpap?utm_source=permalink). The output doesn't look exactly like the form, but it generates a Google Doc with page breaks after every row and you can specify the column titles as an level of heading.

For simplicity it is pretty hard to beat.